# @RequestBody with generic type

Tags: java, spring, generics, jackson

I'm having some problem with Spring MVC 4.2.6 and Jackson (2.7.3). I created an absctract `@RestController` class with a method that uses a generic type. I implement this abstract class passing the type of generic object. I use `@RequestBody` and the `DispatcherServlet` throws `JsonMappingException` (can not construct instance of my class). The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in application context is configured.

**Edit:** More info added.

```
public abstract class AbsctractAnimalResource<DTO extends AnimalDTO> {

    // Doesn't work. Throws JsonMappingException. (@RequestBody)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = POST, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> bar(@RequestBody DTO dto) throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cat")
public class CatResource extends AbsctractAnimalResource<CatDTO> {

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dog")
public class DogResource extends AbsctractAnimalResource<DogDTO> {

}


interface AnimalDTO { }
public class CatDTO implements AnimalDTO { }
public class DogDTO implements AnimalDTO { }
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Ok. More info added. Thanks. I can`t understand, I have debug DispatcherServlet and two annotations have the same behavior, but @RequestBody throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugs in Spring 4.2.6 classes I found this commentary:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java#L51

Spring 4.2.X and Jackson 2.7.X don't work together. I downgraded my Jackson version to 2.6.6 and now everything works. Spring 4.3.X works well with Jackson 2.7+.